# What is a Maggid Meisharim?

Tags: words, names

I understand there is a work by R' Yosef Karo under the same name. But in the Shemos HaTzaddikim, I find the following name:

> ר' מענדיל מגיד מישרים דקהלת באר
>
> R' Mendel, *Maggid Meisharim* of the community in Bar.

What is a *maggid meisharim* in this case?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Hassidism - A New History page 238](https://books.google.com/books?id=5_s4DwAAQBAJ&pg=PA238&lpg=PA238&dq=mendel%20maggid%20meisharim&source=bl&ots=vWDQ50C2Uf&sig=iYZCetqdOC-Az4Vbew4dLkoixfc&hl=en&sa=X&ved=0ahUKEwi76-vmiavXAhUk54MKHYTBDqEQ6AEILjAB#v=onepage&q=mendel%20maggid%20meisharim&f=false), this person was considered a "preacher of the upright". He was a person hired by the community to give sermons on Shabbat and Yom Tov. It seems, as has been common with Hassidic custom, much of the sermon was based on or included Kabbalistic ideas.

It looks like this function became incorporated into a typical shul rav's duties, eventually.